# Dividing column with rule in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns, divide, dplyr

I would like to make a certain column with this rule:
Y2000/S2000=NEW2000
....

This is the example what I want

```
Y2000 Y2001 Y2003 S2000 S2001 S2003 | NEW2000 NEW2001 NEW2003
  5     10    15    1     5     15  |  5/1=5  10/5=2 15/15=1
```

I try to use mutate in dplyr package but I am not familiar with the function.
How do I make the code in R...?

Comment: Ah, I would like to.... NEW2000 to NEW2030 so I want to use the loop or any other function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it for even many columns (years)

Your data

```
df <- data.frame(Y2000=5, Y2001=10, Y2003=15, S2000=1, S2001=5, S2003=15)
```

Define your new column names

```
newcols <- sapply(c(2000,2001,2003), function(i) paste0("NEW",i))
[1] "NEW2000" "NEW2001" "NEW2003"
```

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
          rowwise() %>%
          mutate_(.dots = setNames(paste0(gsub("NEW","Y",newcols),"/",gsub("NEW","S",newcols)), newcols))
```

Output

```
  Y2000 Y2001 Y2003 S2000 S2001 S2003 NEW2000 NEW2001 NEW2003
1     5    10    15     1     5    15       5       2       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you calculate the three columns you have in your desired output.

```
library(dplyr)
your_data %>%
  mutate(
    NEW2000 = Y2000 / S2000,
    NEW2001 = Y2001 / S2001,
    NEW2003 = Y2003 / S2003
  )
```

If you have hundreds of columns like this there are ways to avoid having to type the name of each one.

Comment: Ah, I would like to.... NEW2000 to NEW2030 so I want to use the loop or any other function....

Comment: A better option would be `base R`, i..e. `your_data[paste0("NEW", 2000:2002)] <- your_data[1:3]/your_data[4:6]`

Comment: @akrun is right if you want to go with base R. That example is easier to generalize to `n` columns of data.